# Post values into existing columns and ignore non-existing data

Tags: python, pandas

I have created a DataFrame and want to populate its values across different columns in a different DataFrame.

Dataframe1 is something like:

```
Name Email              Telephone
Brad brad@gmail.com    302 923-9243
Igor igor@gmail.com    303 923-1093
```

And I want to populate an Excel file with columns like this:

```
E-mail   Favorite Food      Name        Games      Number
```

So I'd have to grab all that information from my dataset and populate it there

And I have this:

```
df_2['E-mail'] = df_1['E-mail']
df_2['Name'] = df_1['Name']
df_2['Telephone'] = df_1['Telephone']
```

But it's creating new columns.

How would I just add those rows to existing columns, and leaving blank the ones I have no data from?

Also, note that the telephone column name has changed to Number, and the Email has changed to E-mail, so I can't really merge them, I guess.

Comment: *I want to paste it's values on different columns* The word *Paste* might not have been a good word choice. Since you are dealing with pandas dataframe, it's hard to understand what you mean by paste (maybe it's just me, though:)).

Comment: I get where you are coming from, maybe populate?